# D3 zoom and pan svg ojects independently

Tags: d3.js, zooming

**I would use d3.behavior.zoom to zoom and pan svg ojects independently.**
The problem is that if I go out from an object, d3.event.translate and d3.event.scale changing anyway.
 
When they return to my object this takes new values ​​of d3.event.translate d3.event.scale and  this is wrong. 
Is an example on the internet using d3?  Prefer with d3.behavior.zoom because it has pinch to zoom.
Something like this but zoom does not work: http://vis.uell.net/testcases/d3-drag.html

Comment: Sounds like you want both zoom and drag behaviour? E.g. [here](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1182434).

Comment: Yes. Like this example: http://www.jasondavies.com/poincare-disc/
But I would use many ojects in my svg and have zoom and drag on each one of these

Comment: You still need only one behaviour -- have a look at the many examples for the drag behaviour.